# ssl problems between two tomcat servers

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 7 server (kind of like a web server) that I am trying to have talk to a Tomcat 6 server (acting as a document server on another machine) over SSL and I keep getting this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching rarity64 found.
```

Where `rarity64` is the name of the document server. I've tried exporting keys from both Tomcats keystores and importing them into the others keystores using Java keytool. I've even tried adding them to the other machines cacerts keystore.

I've also used Internet Explorer to import both keys into the other machine. But nothing I try is working.

If it matters the real web server is IIS 7.5, which the Tomcat web server talks too with ARR, and they don't use SSL. But the problem seems to between the two tomcat servers.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

SSL certs are usually signed for the FQDN, and the above error indicates you just used the (short) hostname. Whatever you use to connect, it has to be the CN the cert is signed for.